# Sort a list within the key domain

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a list that looks like this: `my_list = [('a', 4), ('z', 3), ('y', 3), ('x', 3), ('p', 2), ('o', 2)]`.

It is important that the tuples in the list are sorted by the second element ([1]) in the descending order.

Now I need to sort each group of tuples with the same second element in the ascending order based on the first element ([0]) within each group. In other words, I need to get the list

`my_new_list= [('a', 4), ('x', 3), ('y', 3), ('z', 3), ('o', 2), ('p', 2)]`.

How can I write the sorted function with the proper lambda? I can't write just `my_list.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])` because it will break the descending order of the tuples  when they are sorted by their second elements.

What should my lambda look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [('a', 4), ('z', 3), ('y', 3), ('x', 3), ('p', 2), ('o', 2)]

my_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda k: (-k[1], k[0]))
print(my_list)
```

Prints:

```
[('a', 4), ('x', 3), ('y', 3), ('z', 3), ('o', 2), ('p', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your key should be:

```
key=lambda item: (item[0], -item[1])
```